# Foreign key multiple images not saving in django

Tags: python, django, forms, image

i am trying to save a form with multiple images. I have two models post model and images model. The problem is when i try to upload the post the images are not saving. i can upload images in form but when i click Post it only save title, images are not save. Can someone point me what i do wrong please?

**Models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      
class Images(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Post, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    images = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/images/',blank=True, null=True)
```

**Views.py**

```
class CreatePost(CreateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = Createpost
    template_name = 'add_post.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(CreatePost, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        data['form_images'] = PostImageFormSet()
        if self.request.POST:
            data['form_images'] = PostImageFormSet(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
        else:
            data['form_images'] = PostImageFormSet()
        return data

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        context = self.get_context_data()
        form_img = context['form_images']
        atc = form.save(commit=False)
        save = atc.save()
        if form_img.is_valid():
            form_img.instance = save
            form_img.save()
        form.save_m2m()
        return super(CreatePost, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('detail', args=(self.object.id,))
```

**forms.py**

```
class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    image = forms.ImageField(label='Image')
    class Meta:
        model = Images
        exclude = ()
        widgets = {
           'images': forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple':True}),

        }


class CreatePost(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ["title",]


PostImageFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
    Post, Images, form=ImageForm,
    extra=1, can_delete=True, #fields=['images'],
)
```

**templates**

```
<form class="post" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        {% csrf_token %}
            {{form.title.label_tag }} {{ form.title }} <br>
            {{ form_images.management_form }}
                {% for form in form_images.forms %}
                    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                            {% if forloop.first %}
                                {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                                    {{ hidden }}
                                {% endfor %}
                            {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
                            {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }} <br>
                            {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
            <br><br>
            <button type="submit" value="post" id="post">Post</button>
        </form>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your foreignkey to Post really spelled "POst" or was that a typo?

Comment: just typo sorry i think i type wrong when i copy to here

Comment: ah does my question is not suitable to answer??

Comment: Your form_valid logic doesn't look right or conventional to me. I would put a breakpoint at the top of it and step through it to see what's really going on.

Comment: i am new to django how can i add breakpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `'images': forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True})` and `extra=1` is what makes this question different from processing a typical formset. Formsets are used when you want to show multiple instances of the same form. In your question, it appears you want to show one `ImageField` and let the user select multiple. You don't even need formsets if that's the case.

I'll provide a workable example with the formset only being used to render the image field(s) in the form, and from that field, the user can choose multiple images. It can handle `extra=3` but I don't know why someone would need to do that.

**settings.py**

```
...
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'posts.apps.PostsConfig',
]
...

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

**urls.py** (I put in project's URLs file, for this example)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from posts.views import CreatePost, PostDetail

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('add/', CreatePost.as_view(), name='add_post'),
    path('detail/<pk>/', PostDetail.as_view(), name='detail'),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Images(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Post, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    images = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True, null=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory
from .models import Post, Images

class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Images
        fields = ('images',)
        widgets = {
            'images': forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}),
        }

class CreatePostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ["title", ]

PostImageFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
    Post, Images, form=ImageForm,
    extra=1, can_delete=True,  # fields=['images'],
)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import reverse, HttpResponseRedirect
from .models import Post, Images
from django.views.generic import CreateView, DetailView
from .forms import CreatePostForm, PostImageFormSet

class CreatePost(CreateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = CreatePostForm
    template_name = 'posts/add_post.html'
    extra_context = {'form_images': PostImageFormSet()}

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.author = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        for key in form.files:
            img_files = form.files.getlist(key)
            for file in img_files:
                Images.objects.create(images=file, article=self.object)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data(form=form)
        return self.render_to_response(context)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.id})

class PostDetail(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'posts/detail.html'
    pk_url_kwarg = 'pk'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

**add_post.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
      .p-5 {
        padding: 150px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="p-5">
      <form class="post" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %} {{ form.title.label_tag }} {{ form.title }} <br>
        {{ form_images.management_form }}
        {% for form in form_images.forms %}
          {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
            {% if forloop.first %}
              {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                {{ hidden }}
              {% endfor %}
              {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
              {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }} <br>
            {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
        <br><br>
        <button type="submit" value="post" id="post">Post</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**detail.html**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
      img {
        height: auto;
        width: 200px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
    {% for img in post.images_set.all %}
    <div>
      <img src="{{ img.images.url }}" alt="{{ img.name }}">
    </div>
    {% empty %}
      <p>No images</p>
    {% endfor %}
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: OMG thanks you so much @Jarad. You save my day:D . I been trying for hundred times. Your code is perfectly work. Thanks again :D